# How to implement an abstact class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following abstract class:

```
class  Weapon
{
  public:
    Weapon(std::string const &name) : _name(name) {}
    virtual void attack() const = 0;
    std::string const &getName() const;
  private:
    std::string const &_name;
};
```

A simple implemntation

```
class Shadowmourn : public Weapon 
{
  public:
    ShadowMourn() : Weapon(std::string("Shadowmourn")) {}

    void attack() const override {}
}
```

I can compile it but I got some strange characters when I try to print the name of my devired class.

```
Weapon *w = new Shadowmourn();
std::cout << "got " << w->getName() << std::endl;
std::cout << "got " << w->getName().c_str() << std::endl;
```

Both output are not the expected ones.. I got some unreadable characters.. So do I have a bad implementation of my Weapon class?

Comment: some squares with some white and black spaces.. Im under temrinator on linux

Comment: A dangling reference. `std::string const &_name;` -> `std::string _name;`

Comment: @E_net4 Let me check... no.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What u mean?

Comment: Why do you use reference types there?

Comment: `std::string("Shadowmourn")` stops existing after you construct your object, which invalidates all references to it, including `Weapon::_name`.

Comment: Why not? It's an object like another

Comment: `std::string const &_name;` remove & as HolyBlackCat suggested

Comment: Ok i get it, cuz it's on the stack..

Comment: @Romeortec If a class type has a reference type data member means, you probably can't meaningfully assign to instances of that type. It's not wrong, but you might run into annoying problems later down the line.

Comment: yes, Im just gonna replace std::string("Shadowmourn") by new std::string("Shadowmourn") and then remove it in the destructor :)

Comment: @Romeortec Beware that doing so will also cause you problems. Read about the [`rule of 3/5/0`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Just use value semantics. There's no reason here not to just use `std::string`.

Comment: @Romeortec: What makes you believe you should use `new` here?! Don't do that!

Comment: Bad form!  Don't do a "new".  Just have it as an object, not a pointer, not as a reference.

Comment: Alright lmao, thanks

Comment: why ppl down my topic, salty men x)

Comment: Your title is a click bait probably that's why you get down voted.

Comment: Why is `Weapon` an abstract class? As the number of weapons grow in your game, you will need to write a **lot** of code. Instead, you `Weapon` should have all the attributes which every weapon defines and then you can create instances of `Weapon` for different things like "sword", "axe", "slingshot", etc.

Comment: And if you run into a few weapons that do have radically different behaviour, you can still override a virtual function to do the extra weird stuff.

Comment: @user4581301: I think that's all just extremely speculative. We don't know anything about this game, its rules, its requirements, its design and its scope.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice im just learning cpp with some basic implementations. Of course this abstract class is totally useless, but no that useless for learning inheritance

Comment: @Romeortec I understand the utility for learning the mechanics of inheritance here. However, I suggest learning that with examples that show good uses of it.

Answer (score 10):

You invoke undefined behaviour because you store a reference to a `std::string` which is destroyed even though the containing `Weapon` lives on, and then you try to access the already destroyed `std::string`.

Strange output is one of the many unpredictable things which can happen in such a situation.

The solution is to make your code simpler: don't store a `std::string const&` but a `std::string const`.

```
class  Weapon
{
  public:
    Weapon(std::string const &name) : _name(name) {}
    virtual void attack() const = 0;
    std::string const &getName() const;
  private:
    std::string const _name;
};
```

You also need a virtual destructor, and you may want to get rid of the underscore convention for your data members. And you may just want to make `getName` return by value to avoid further trouble with dangling references. And while we're at it, classes with virtual functions are always good candidates for deleted copy constructors and copy assignment operators.

```
class  Weapon
{
  public:
    Weapon(std::string const &name) : name(name) {}
    virtual ~Weapon() = default;
    Weapon(Weapon const&) = delete;
    Weapon& operator=(Weapon const&) = delete;
    virtual void attack() const = 0;
    std::string getName() const;
  private:
    std::string const name;
};
```

Comment: `virtual ~Weapon() = default;`?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Good idea. Old habits die hard :)

Comment: Also  `const std::string& getName() const;`? +1 though, naturally.

Comment: There's also a question of rather you really want `name` to be `const` or not. Being `const` makes your type non-assignable and non-movable.

Comment: @Bathsheba: What you mean, exactly? I've simplified that function on purpose, because I suspect the OP made it return a reference for "performance reasons". Don't you agree with that?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Returning `std::string` from `getName()` is premature pessimization. I believe it has worse performance in every use case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yes, but in my experience, object-oriented classes (i.e. ones with virtual functions) should almost never be assigned or moved, so the `const` data member costs you nothing.

Comment: If the weapon name was "Strange Collector's Professional Specialized Genuine Vintage Killstreak X", for example, then not taking a value copy might save a bit of CPU burn, innit.

Comment: Profile, profile, profile.  I've found most of my performance bottlenecks are not where I would have guessed that they were.  And I have never found a micro-optimization to be that critical.  (Taking both premature optimization, balanced with premature pessimization to heart.)

Comment: @Eljay: In addition to that, I'd say even profiling might be a waste of time if nobody ever notices or complains about performance problems.

Comment: You may want to make that member const or delete copy ctor and assignment operator (I really doubt OP needs either). But have them both. hmm